# onSubmit Post issue with IE

Tags: internet-explorer, onsubmit

In one assignment, i'm using onblur to "validate" a field. To ensure that the active field will be blurred upon submission (if the user presses enter or clicks on the submit button without first losing focus of active field). Works fine in Chrome but does not work properly in IE. I have a code similar to this:

< form-open onSubmit="document.activeelement.blur()">

< input name="field" onBlur="Round to whole number" >

< submit-button >

< form-close >

Say I enter 24.27 and then I press enter while the form is still active, the value will change to 24 in Chrome but in IE, the value that will be posted will still be 24.27

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 0):

arrived at a solution myself. don't use onblur. use onchange on the actual field.